# cocos2d update delta 's unit is seconds?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

What is the unit of delta parameter of update() function in cocos2d?

Is it second?

I can't seem to find a doc that says anything about delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [API](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a7e0c230d398bba56d690e025544cb745) and the [documention](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3adraw_update#update) the delta time is in second.

Comment: I'm using cocos2d-x3.2, in my lua script I have to use (delta time/10)  to get the right second value